# Does aws.config.credentials only handle one user at a time? Because globalSignout is signing all users out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In my app I logged into two instances of my app. I am setting my credentials using aws.config.credentials as seen below:

If I am dealing with multiple users at a time, is doing this replace the previous user? How can I handle multiple users logging in?

```js
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'ca-central-1:XXXX',
  Logins: { // optional tokens, used for authenticated login
    'cognito-idp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/XXX': val
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this client-side code? If yes I'd expect the sdk to store the data in your site's cookie. This means parallel sessions are more difficult, but you can always use Incognito Mode in your Browser (which effectively adds an empty session) or another Browser.

Comment: @Maurice this is node server side code using cogniti api. The thing is ive tried logging in from two different computers and when i signout user (the signout happens automatically after a file is uploaded to s3) on one computer its signing out all users. I want to only limit it to that specific user. I think it has to do with my aws.config credentials when i am setting them its setting one user not keeping list of all users. Is there way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. It was simple but some reason easy to miss. I was not setting the credentials with the users token before making the particular api call.

So when I signed out one user, other users seemed to come back as signedout (which was actually an error in my logic), because when I tried to access an api from another user who was signed in, the credentials were old (stale). So I had to use the token which I passed for that particular user and set the credentials before accessing the api